# href in area tag not clickable in android gmail app

Tags: android, html, email, gmail

Following code is the part of HTML email. It works in all browsers but in android Gmail App it's not working.

```
<area  alt="" title="" href="http://google.com" shape="rect" coords="754,1338,1044,1602" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Emails are supposed to be coded with simple html. Try using an anchor tag and give it a style, something like below:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="font-family:Arial;display:inline-block; width:230px; background-color:#000001; color:#ffffff;padding:10px;">link text here</a>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm having problem in that particular scenario(Android Gmail App), whereas it works in other browsers and desktop browsers.

Comment: Hats why I said use anchor not area. Not all email clients render all html elements.

Comment: I understand but in current scenario, i don't have any option. I can only go with map tag as we're using a graphic to be mapped.

Comment: You said gmail app, is the image resizing to fit the screen? Image maps are based on an area on an image. Once the image starts resizing the area however doesnt reduce in size. You image map is still working just not within the image. Also there is no walk around for this unless you want to force the desktop version to be shown to users.

Comment: No, it's not responsive. I know what you're trying to say. But I want to solve this exact problem on Gmail App, Can you help me with that rather than suggesting me to use any other method?

Comment: If you image is resizing then you need to force the Gmail app to show the desktop version. Place a spacer image with Max and min width which is the width of your template. It will force Gmail app to show the desktop version. Your image map will start working

Comment: Gmail App is showing desktop version and I tried your method but it didn't work. btw Thanks